# htaccess link redirect adds parameter

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to redirect old menu item to new with htaccess. It works but it adds parameter i do not want. Code is:

```
Redirect 301 /menu_cars_old.html http://www.domain.com/menu_cars_new.html
RewriteRule ^/?(menu_+[A-Za-z._-]+)$ index.php?menu=$1 [NC,L]
```

I am not familiar with htaccess so I am asking for help. The Redirect 301 statement should do the trick but i think it has something to do with my rewrite rule.

Redirected link then looks like http://www.domain.com/menu_cars_new.html?menu=menu_cars_old.html.

If i change it to

```
Redirect 301 /menu_cars_old.html http://www.domain.com/?menu=menu_cars_new.html
```

it works but i don't want parameter in URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix mod_alias and mod_rewrite rules. Here is how you should have it:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?menu_cars_old\.html$ http://www.domain.com/menu_cars_new.html [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/?(menu_+[\w.-]+)$ index.php?menu=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Make sure to place this code in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rewrite *"/menu_`$any`"* into *"/index.php?menu=menu_`$any`"* and to redirect *"/menu_cars_old.html"* into *"/menu_cars_new.html"*, then try these directives:

```
# once per htaccess
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/?(menu_([A-Za-z_-]+))$ /index.php?menu=$1
RewriteRule ^/?menu_cars_old.html$ /menu_cars_new.html [R=301,L]
```